# Android: How to turn Anti-Aliasing off for TextView and Layout

Tags: android, colors, paint

When I draw text in TextView or fill background color in LinearLayout,
I found something weird which cannot be found in Windows programming.

```
The background color in the Layout and text color in TextView,
are not a single color, but a mixed color
when I capture the phone screen and see and check the pixel value on the PC.
```

If I set the text color or as 0xFF1010FF (Blue),
most of the pixels are 0xFF1010FF,
a few of them are 0xFF1010FD or 0xFF1010FE, a slight different color value,
I guess it is for anti-aliasing.

So does Layout Background Color. (1 or 2 value difference for each pixel)

These effect the color looks smoother in android than PC,
but I don't want to fill color like that, but just with exact color value.

```
Can I make the color with an exact single value?
```

I tried `TextPaint.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);` but it didn't work.

Moreover, I may not be able to use TextPaint for the Layout Background.

This question will be a common issue for most android developers,
so I will be very appreciated for any of your advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, and it worked for me :

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView1.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);
```

This effectively disables antialising, so IMO it's not to be done, but if it's what you're looking for, there you go.